# Best way to convert MDB into MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, csv

I have lots of MDB files and want to insert them into MySQL, found a way to convert them into CSV, but they have not the same columns so it would be hard to open one by one and get the column numbers of them.

Is there a way to convert in bulk, mdb to mysql ?

Found Bullzip but it only does one by one

Comment: You have posted your question here on Stack Overflow, which is "a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers" (ref: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)), so presumably you intend to do some programming. Please [edit] your question to indicate the platform (e.g., Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, ...) and environment/language(s) you might use (e.g., Access VBA, VB.NET, C#, ...). Also indicate whether you have a copy of Access available (for VBA or COM automation).

Comment: why some much hate ? this question have not been answerd yet here so why are ppl hating it ?

Comment: If your question is not about *programming* then it is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [EMS Data Pump for MySQL](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/datapump)